# Yii2: is it possible to execute a controller's function without reloading page?

Tags: jquery, view, controller, yii2

I have a [button](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/helper-html#buttons) that has to execute the a `actionCreate()` function of my controller but it doesn't have to redirect to any page or reload the page. 
Is it possible without using Ajax? I can use **jQuery**.

My view:

```
<?= Html::button('Save student', ['id' => 'saveStudent']) ?>
```

My controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Students();
    $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())
    $model->save();
}
```

Comment: The button is clicked in web browser that runs on user's PC. The `actionCreate()` is executed by php modul on your web server. So browser must send some request to server to tell it that the create action should be executed. And it can be either standard request (page reload) or an ajax request. Without any request the server doesn't know that user clicked the button.

Comment: for this you could take a look at  how pjax components work http://blog.neattutorials.com/yii2-pjax-tutorial/    https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/772/pjax-on-activeform-and-gridview-yii2